# Select MySQL with multipe conditions (MAX)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so I have a table with topics and I am trying to select the latest topic from every category.

`category_id` is the category and `date` is the date created.

I cant actually find out what is the command I have to execute in order to get the latest topic of the category and then select its data.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I want to find the proper command so I can select topic with id 2 from category 1 and topic with id 3 from category 2

Hope it helps you understand what am I talking about.

```
id   category_id   content   date
1    2             bla bla   12-1-2017 22:54 
2    1             bla bla   12-1-2017 22:58 - latest
3    2             bla bla   12-1-2017 22:57 - latest
4    1             bla bla   12-1-2017 22:55
```

Comment: you'll have to show what you've tried already. your question is too vague.

Comment: Table schema, sample data and expected results would help us help you.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(``date``) FROM table GROUP BY category_id`

Comment: Edited the post guys, sorry for being so vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform multiple `WHERE` conditions in your select.

```
SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Smith';
```

Or even conditional based on other factors:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (FirstName = 'John' OR FirstName = 'Jennifer') AND (LastName = 'Smith' OR LastName = 'Jones');
```

[Here's an easy to follow guide](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/13/multiple-where-conditions)

Note the `AND` condition in the SQL command.

SO based on what you want:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from `table` WHERE id = 2 AND category_id = 3"
```

Comment: The closest approach of what I have on my mind right is something like `SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id=2 AND date=MIN(date)` but it doesnt work at all

Comment: what is the order of your columns in the SQL?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you wanted. Actually @PM 77's answer seems correct: `SELECT MIN(``date``) FROM table GROUP BY category_id`

Comment: Ive actually figured it out by myselft thanks for the answer mate. `SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id=3 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1` works too :)